# can't debug my program anymore

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, compiler-errors

While I was working on a project in C#.NET, I had a power failure and now I can't debug my program. These are the errors that occur.

```
Error   1   Unable to copy file "C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecInternational.mdf" to "bin\Debug\InfortecInternational.mdf". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecInternational.mdf' because it is being used by another process. InfortecManagementSystem

Error   2   Unable to copy file "C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecInternational_log.ldf" to "bin\Debug\InfortecInternational_log.ldf". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecManagementSystem\InfortecInternational_log.ldf' because it is being used by another process. InfortecManagementSystem
```

How can I make it work again?

Comment: Try restarting SQL-server. using start-> run -> services.msc

Comment: some program has locked your files. Try to restart vs.net to check if it is vs.net. If not, see what other programs use the program and log out/restart to see if that works.

Comment: Go to your Service Task Manager End Process the applications that might be using your .mdf files like your management studio or something else. After that, try Rebuilding your solutions again. Make sure there are no compile errors. Good Luck!

Comment: There's no other program using my database. It is used only in VS with the project. I tried restarting VS and even my computer. Both didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The files are locked by another process.  [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) is a Windows/SysInternals tool which helps with this problem.  It will tell you what process is currently using those files.

Download handle, go to command prompt and type "handle 'C:\Users\Nihal\Documents\Visual Studio 2005'".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the responses. Manual deletion of files and then rebuilding didn't work out. I found this somewhere and it did work.

```
In Solution Explorer>Properties>Build Events,
In 'Pre-build event command line',

    del C: \ SampleProject \ SampleProject \ bin \ Debug \ database.mdf 
    del C: \ SampleProject \ SampleProject \ bin \ Debug \ database.ldf
```

Here's [the link](http://translate.google.lk/translate?hl=en&sl=vi&u=http://vozforums.com/archive/index.php%3Ft-226125.html&ei=tbFbTtL2DI7SrQfmwoSwCg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB8Q7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dbuild%2Berror-Unable%2Bto%2Bcopy%2Bfile%2B%2522database.mdf%2522%2Bto%2B%2522bin%255CDebug%255Cdatabase.mdf%2522.%2BThe%2Bprocess%2Bcannot%2Baccess%2Bthe%2Bfile%2B%2527database.mdf%2527%2Bbecause%2Bit%2Bis%2Bbeing%2Bused%2Bby%2Banother%2Bprocess.%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dopera%26hs%3D3Ak%26rls%3Den%26channel%3Dsuggest%26biw%3D990%26bih%3D633%26prmd%3Divns) .

Answer (score 0):

The original files appear to be locked, so they can't be rebuilt.  If you have some sort of file unlocker, that should work.  Otherwise, just delete them from their current locations and allow them to be rebuilt when you next try to run in debug mode.

Comment: thank you for the responses. Manual deletion of files and then rebuilding didn't work out. I found this somewhere and it did work.

    In Solution Explorer>Properties>Build Events,
    In 'Pre-build event command line',

        del C: \ SampleProject \ SampleProject \ bin \ Debug \ database.mdf 
        del C: \ SampleProject \ SampleProject \ bin \ Debug \ database.ldf